# I need to add and remove classes on scroll and when a menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive-design, webflow

I'm trying to add and remove the active class on when a user scrolls on my navbar. When it is docked at the top of the page I want it to be transparent and if a user scrolls > 1 I want it to turn white.

I got it to work on desktop but on mobile screens I'm running into the issue of it not adding the active class or adding the class and then removing it completely when the menu is open and a user is at the top of the page.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
// mobile active class toggle 
// THIS IS WHAT IS NOT WORKING!!!
// when a user clicks on the menu button I want to check if the YOffset < 1[docked] and if the menu is open. If so I want to keep the active class. If it doesn't match both statements I want to remove the active class. 

var menu = document.getElementById('menuBtn');
menu.addEventListener("click", function() { 
  var nav = document.getElementById('navBar');
  if(window.pageYOffset < 1 && menu.classList.contains('w--open')) {
    nav.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    nav.classList.add('active'); 
  }  
});
  
document.getElementsByClassName('.nav-link').addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.getElementById('navBar').classList.remove('active'); 
 document.getElementById('menuBtn').classList.remove('w--open');
});
</script>


<div>
  <a href="/" aria-current="page" class="brand w-nav-brand w--current"></a>
  <nav role="navigation" class="nav-menu w-nav-menu">
    <div data-hover="" data-delay="0" class="dropdown w-dropdown">      
      <nav>
        <a class="nav-link"></a>
        <a class="nav-link"></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div data-hover="" data-delay="0" class="dropdown w-dropdown">
      <nav>
        <a class="nav-link"></a>
        <a class="nav-link"></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="menuBtn" class="menu-button w-nav-button">
     <div class="icon w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a preview link of the site. [Tech For Campaigns](https://tech-for-campaigns.webflow.io/)

Comment: It looks to me as if you always set the `nav` classList to contain active. Maybe it's a typo? But after your `if-else` you add it back no matter what happens in the `if-else`

Comment: If you want to toggle 'active' in the classList, why not use `nav.classList.toggle('active')`

Comment: @ryanWilson Thanks for catching that, it was a typo! I thought I deleted it.

Comment: @Marisa One of your conditions to remove the active class is: `menu.classList.contains('w--open')`, do you ever add this class back to `menu`? It looks to me like as soon as you click on a `nav-link` this class is removed, but I don't see where you add it back.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Sharing only an active implementation is against [SO] guidelines, for several reasons: *a)* potential fixes can't be tested; *b)* once you find a fix you'll likely apply it to the website and future users won't be able to see the initial problem, which would greatly reduce the usefulness of your question. In turn, this greatly reduces your chances of getting an answer. Additionally, the problem is not with the function bound on `menu`, but with the one bound on `.nav-link`.